# PATH error in Bash

Tags: python, linux, bash, path, cx-freeze

I am using CentOS6 Bash and trying to use Python & cx_Freeze. I am a not familiar with PATH and Path modifications and this being the server, I am a little apprehensive to try it myself (but I have to). When I try $cx_f/Freeze, I get `-bash: cx_Freeze: command not found` -- same goes for any cx_Freeze setup.py, etc, ... attempts (including `module not found` ). My goal is to use cx_freeze (a Python bundling tool). The o/p from Bash is as follows.

```
$ which python
  /usr/bin/python

$ sudo locate -b python | fgrep -w bin
[sudo] password for xyz: 

/usr/bin/abrt-action-analyze-python
/usr/bin/pip-python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python-config
/usr/bin/python-pip
/usr/bin/python2
/usr/bin/python2.6
/usr/bin/python2.6-config
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/python
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/ispythonversion2
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/ispythonversion2inbin
```

cx_Freeze is apparently located at /usr/lib/Python2.6/site-packages as evidenced by this o/p

```
[xyz@server ~]$ ls
cpu  perl5  usr  xyz
[xyz@server ~]$ cd usr
[xyz@server usr]$ cd lib
[xyz@server lib]$ ls
python2.6
[xyz@server lib]$ cd python2.6
[xyz@server python2.6]$ ls
site-packages
[xyz@server python2.6]$ cd site-packages
[xyz@server site-packages]$ ls
cx_Freeze  cx_Freeze-4.3.1-py2.6.egg-info
[xyz@server site-packages]$ cd cx_Freeze
[xyz@server cx_Freeze]$ ls
bases     finder.py   freezer.pyc  hooks.pyo     initscripts  main.py   setupwriter.py   windist.py
dist.py   finder.pyc  freezer.pyo  __init__.py   macdist.py   main.pyc  setupwriter.pyc  windist.pyc
dist.pyc  finder.pyo  hooks.py     __init__.pyc  macdist.pyc  main.pyo  setupwriter.pyo  windist.pyo
dist.pyo  freezer.py  hooks.pyc    __init__.pyo  macdist.pyo  samples   util.so
```

And, then again:

```
[xyz@server ~]$ ls
cpu  cpu.py  perl5  usr  xyz
[xyz@server ~]$ cd usr
[xyz@server usr]$ ls
bin  lib  share
[xyz@server usr]$ cd bin
[xyz@server bin]$ ls
cxfreeze  cxfreeze-quickstart
[xyz@server bin]$ cxfreeze-quickstart
-bash: cxfreeze-quickstart: command not found
```

So, this makes me even more confused about the location of the cx_Freeze installation! To worsen things, as BM said "But wait, there's more!"

```
[xyzserver ~]$ sudo locate -b site-packages
[sudo] password for xyz: 
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages
/usr/share/xemacs/site-packages
```

Why are there so many site-packages. The ones at /lib/ and /lib64/ have different contents and the one at /lib/ contains what I need -- although neither have cx_Freeze.

(I have removed the Python, site-packages results from the example above which corresponded to the virtualenv that I created because it is something I understand and may complicate things.)

EDIT:

```
[xyz@server ~]$ echo $PATH
/opt/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin:/home/vtripathi/perl5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local  /sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/vtripathi/bin
```

EDIt-2.0:

```
[xyz@server ~]$ ls
cpu  cpu.py  perl5  usr  xyz
[xyz@server ~]$ cd usr
[xyz@server usr]$ cd bin
[xyz@server bin]$ ls
cxfreeze  cxfreeze-quickstart
[xyz@server bin]$ cd cxfreeze
-bash: cd: cxfreeze: Not a directory
[xyz@server bin]$ pwd
/home/xyz/usr/bin
```

EDIT-3.0:

```
[xyz@server ~]$ PATH=/usr/lib/python2.6
[xyz@server ~]$ $PATH
-bash: /usr/lib/python2.6: is a directory
[xyz@server ~]$ PATH=/usr/lib/
[xyz@server ~]$ $PATH
-bash: /usr/lib/: is a directory
[xyz@server ~]$
```

Comment: You can interactively change `PATH` in an interactive terminal; it will affect only the interactive shell in that terminal (and not the rest of the system). So experimenting is quite easy. Don't forget to use `which`

Comment: Could you pls. explain what it is to 'interactively change PATH'? Thx.

Comment: Type in your terminal `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:` *somethingelse*  and repeat that till you are happy with your `PATH`.

Comment: Thx. I want to see if I can get cx_freeze at /lib in my path. I tried the option but didn't work. I've added the o/p under EDIT-3.0 at the bottom of the question.

Comment: There are some things you seem confused about. `cx_Freeze` is a Python module, so you use it by doing `import cx_Freeze` in Python. The command you can run from a system shell is `cxfreeze`. `~` is shorthand for your home directory (`/home/xyz`). Your cxfreeze command is in `/home/xyz/usr/bin`, which is *not* the same as `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $PATH
```

Is ~/usr/bin on there? Or wherever the location of cx_freeze is, you don't clarify

Comment: Thx. I forgot to add it. Added the o/p at the bottom of the question. cx_freeze is I think at /usr/bin/ - given the o/p above.

Comment: It looks to me like it's at ~/usr/bin, if I see what properly, could you "pwd" when you're there?

Comment: Added an edit-2.0 section - let me know if that doesn't help. Thx.